# Docker container with persistent disk, how to rebase without turn off docker containers

Tags: git, docker, web-deployment, persistent-storage

I have a monolithic application running on Docker, and for the databases, I'm using persistent disk for SQL and NoSQL databases.

The problem is, everytime I deploy a new version, these persistent disk must be commited and push to the repository and the size are really big.

Then there is also a time when the commit between local and origin are different.
What is the best way to handle persistent disk?
and how can I deploy with zero downtime caused by this persistent disks.

Comment: Can you describe your workflow in more detail?  How do you build a new image when there is a new build of your software?  How do you mount the persistent disks into the containers?  (What is the "commit and push" step exactly?)

Comment: I'm using docker-compose, declaring the persistent volume in docker-compose.yml.
Sorry myb I'm using a different term, should be persistent volume instead of persistent disk. Commit and push as regular git repository, then in production server basically just pull and build the image and run it in the container.

Git will always be failed to pull, because there was some changes uncommited in the local caused by persistent volume.

Comment: You're asking 2 different questions it seems, and they both seem too vague. The best way to handle using volumes? It depends on what you want to do I'm afraid. How can I deploy with zero downtime? Also depends on what you are trying to do. It does sound like you should consider storing your database in cloud storage, and retrieving it. For large file storage, you shouldn't be using git (typically).

Comment: You should be able to launch new containers, with updated images, against the existing data volumes, without "committing" anything.  How are files getting modified in the container on the production system that would need to be reflected in source control?

Comment: @DavidMaze you mean like put those folders in .gitignore? let me check and will inform you the result, I remember I put those in gitignore, but not sure right now

Comment: @mikey I will try to convert my local noSQL to cloud database, but it needs more time, thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @DavidMaze I didnt put it in gitignore, but at the first few months, everything works fine like what you explains.. I can deploy without any problem. Somehow it suddenly appears that I cant deploy because of those changes in persistent volume. Till now still don't know what causing that issue.

Comment: It isn't clear to me that this will help, but if the issue is that your large files are being copied into the container during build of the image then a docker ignore file could potentially help: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file . It sounded more like the issue was on subsequent container runs. It still sounds like the core issue is managing large files via git. If you could update the original question with steps + screenshots + commands it would be easier to help.